# Hibernate Validation and byte code enhancement

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator, byte-code-enhancement

Can anyone help  me in understanding the meaning of this section in Hibernate Validation reference documentation.

> When validating byte code enhanced objects property level constraints should be used, because the byte code enhancing library won’t be able to determine a field access via reflection. [[1](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-bean-constraints.html#d0e330)]

Comment: If I had to lodge a guess, I'd say that this means that if you are using libraries that byte code enhance your objects (Spring does this in some cases, but I assume there are JPA providers that also do this), you should place your validation constraint annotations on the getters of the object, instead of at the individual private field level.

Answer (score 2):

An byte-code enhancing library automatically adds code to your written classes. The enhancer post-processes the byte-code generated by your Java compiler, adding fields or methods to implement a required feature. Byte-code enhancement is happen generally during build-time or run-time. Libraries which are using byte-code enhancing are among others Spring, Hibernate 5, openJPA and lombok.

Therefore, if you are using a 'byte code enhancing library' then you should definitely use property level constraints because hibernate validator is using reflection for validation and a reflection access on a field will not (for sure) cover the byte code enhanced property.

For example you have the following simple class.

```
public class Person {

    @NotNull
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Now you are using or have implemented a byte-code enhancer which add the following feature to your code (of course during build or run-time in your byte-code).

```
public class Person {

    @NotNull
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        if(this.name == null)
            return "";
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Then the bean validation comes into play. If you are using field annotation than the field `name` is accessed by reflection directly and gets validated. The validation fails.

But when you are using property annotation the bean validation will access the filed `name` by the `getName()` method to determine if the field name is valid. And the validation pass.